# Deploying private EC2 instance (say Ec2.pem) and Bastion host (say BastionKey.pem) with different SSH Keys - AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, amazon-vpc

I understand that it is not recommended to ask multiple question in a single post but they are all tightly coupled hence asking them under one post.

I was trying to SSH to a private EC2 instance in a VPC from the internet using Bastion host. I came across 2 approaches.
**NOTE** When I launched my private EC2 instance and Bastion host I chose different Keys.(In both the approaches I saw the authors used same Keys for EC2 and the Bastion)

**Approach 1**: Configuring SSH ProxyCommand as illustrated in [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpFAHis4O4g](http://ProxyCommand)

Approach 2: ssh-agent command with ssh -A option [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/](http://ssh-agent)

**Question 1:** In approach 2, I did

```
ssh-add ~/Downloads/Ec2.pem
ssh-add ~/Downloads/BastionKey.pem
```

Is my approach of adding both the keys to the ssh-agent correct? This way I was able ssh into Bastion as a first step and then as a second step I had to explicitly ssh into private EC2.

**Question 2:** Approach 1 is against the idea of (Approach 2) 2 step ssh process but proposes ProxyCommand so that end user should be able to directly ssh into the private EC2 in a single step. This way a system admin of Bastion host will not have control of ssh-ing to individual EC2 instances.In fact the author demonstrates that if you ssh into Bastion host (it will succeed) and then ssh to EC2 it fails. Is my understanding correct here?

**Question 3:** Approach 1 is not working for me. I used the same structure for ~/.ssh/config but with different Key file paths. I am unable to ssh to my private EC2 directly. I even tried the 2 step process but I can only login into Bastion host, I cannot ssh to EC2. All my Security groups, ACL, Internet gateway, NAT gateway and VPC settings are fine, otherwise Approach 2 wouldn't have worked. What could I be doing wrong?

```
cat ~/.ssh/config 
HOST bastion
Hostname ec2-5x-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
User ec2-user
IdentityFile /Users/myname/Downloads/BastionKey.pem

HOST *.ec2.internal
User ec2-user
IdentityFile /Users/myname/Downloads/Ec2.pem
ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion
```

**Question 4:** Which is the recommend approach among 1 & 2 and what additional steps must be followed when different keys are chosen for Bastion and EC2?

**Error output:**

```
ssh -v ip-10-0-1-12.ec2.internal
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myname/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/myname/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for *.ec2.internal
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q -W ip-10-0-1-12.ec2.internal:22 bastion
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/Downloads/Ec2.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/Downloads/Ec2.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
/bin/false: No such file or directory
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

```
HOST bastion
Hostname ec2-example-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com
User ec2-user
IdentityFile /Users/myname/Downloads/BastionKey.pem

HOST *.ec2.internal
User ec2-user
IdentityFile /Users/myname/Downloads/Ec2/Ec2.pem
ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion
```

Try using the bastions public DNS name in your ssh config, also use the internal ec2 DNS name for the one behind the VPC. (AWS DNS is sketchy at best sometimes)

Note: *.ec2.internal assums you will use the same ssh key for each ec2 you need to access proxying through your bastion. If this is not the case replace *.ec2.internal with whatever-internal-ip.ec2.internal and add an entry for each individual ec2.

Hope this can fix your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I have updated the original question with the config file you suggested (DNS names), I also pasted the verbose ssh output. I am surprised that the ssh-agent/ssh-add method works and I can ssh to my private IP but the ProxyCommand method does not. Unable to figure out what is going wrong here.